# Question about a Proof of the Commutativity of Iterated Limits.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have questions about a proof I came up with for the commutativity of iterated limits. In particular, I am wondering if this proof for this theorem is valid.

**Theorem**: Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $(0,0).$ Suppose $\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} f(x,y)$ exists for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and suppose $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x,y)$ exists for each $y \in \mathbb{R}.$ Then $$f(0,0)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0 }\lim_{y \rightarrow 0 } f(x,y) =\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x,y).$$

*Proof*: We will prove the first equality, as the latter equality can be deduced by a very similar argument. Let $\psi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $$\psi(x)=\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} f(x,y).$$ This function is well-defined, which follows from our assumption $\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} f(x,y)$ exists for each $x.$  We wish to prove $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \psi(x)=f(0,0).$

Suppose $\epsilon>0.$ By the continuity of $f$ at $(0,0),$ we choose $\delta>0$ such that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$ implies $$|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$ Now, for each $|x| < \frac{\delta}{\sqrt{2}},$ since $\psi(x)=\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} f(x,y),$ we can choose a $|y_x|< \frac{\delta}{\sqrt{2}}$ such that $$|\psi(x)-f(x,y_x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

So if $|x|<\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{2}},$ we have by the triangle inequality
$$|\psi(x)-f(0,0)| \le |\psi(x)-f(x,y_x)|+|f(x,y_x)-f(0,0)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} =\epsilon.$$

**Questions**

1. Is this proof valid ? In particular, is the argument involving $y_x$ correct ?
2. Is there a proof of the theorem that circumvents the use of an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument ? More specifically, can we prove the theorem using only properties of limits.

Comment: Looks good, Vivek. I cannot see any flaw.

Comment: @amsmath, thanks. Do you have any idea on answering Question 2 ?